# What are acceptable values for the NumberOfReclaimedConnections performance counter?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-performance, performancecounter

I am trying to investigate an ASP.NET application which is experiencing a lot of intermittent SQL timeout errors. I am looking out the NumberOfReclaimedConnections performance counter, and it is currently standing at about 1000.

How can I tell whether this is an acceptable value for the size of my application?

Answer (score 4):

Really, it should be Zero.  When that counter increments, it indicates that a connection was closed (reclaimed), but not because your code properly called Dispose(), Close(), or used a "using" clause.  In that case, the connection is not being returned to the pool as quickly as it could be, and so could run out.

Make sure that you are always disposing those connections, and the counter should remain at zero.